# GAE Memcached API

Tags: google-app-engine, memcached

I followed https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/usingmemcache, and got memcached work.

but I have a problem when I try to update cache before it expires.
for example, after:

```
"memcache.add('key', data, 60000000000)"
```

if I want to update the information stores in "key"

I was hoping there was an API of

> "memcache.update('key', newData, 60000000000)" (NO)

I tried to add again:

> "memcache.add('key', newData, 60000000000)"

but it doesn't work. It didn't replace the previous one.

Anyone can give me some ideas how to do it?

I know there is a

> "memcahed.flush_all()"

But it flush the whole cache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `memcache.set('key', data, 60000000000)` to set the value, regardless of previous contents in cache. See:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/functions

Comment: oh, thanks. it is really helpful. I was trying to use mecache.delete('key'). Thanks again.